# How to migrate new created plone site's groups and roles to a old one?

Tags: plone

Plone4.2.5 upgraded from 4.1.4 with many users.

Compared to a new created plone site (4.2.5), there is no group and role for "site adminstrator" on my upgraded old plone site. So I plan to migrate new created plone site's groups and roles to the old one.

I know how to migrate old sites' users, groups and roles to a new plone site: export/import acl_users, portal_memberdata, portal_membership.  But no idea how to use new created plone site's groups and roles without prejudice to  users in the old plone site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you should worry about, your member-mangement has stayed unchanged and that's good, nobody wants implicit changes in that area.

The group 'Site administrators' was introduced to achieve a better distinction between ZMI-admins (group 'Administrators') and Site-admins. You may or may not use it (assign users to the group), depending on your requirements.

Remember that the workflows, groups and roles Plone ships with OOTB, are suggestions/skeletons for most use-cases. The responsibility in defining a site's security requirements is (and should be) on one's own authority.